# Configuring replication after mirroring - is this possible?

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring, database-replication, database-mirroring

I'm currently setting up replication in order to produce a database that will be used to run reports and take load of the main database.

According to the guide at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799(v=SQL.90).aspx

You setup mirroring, which we use for high availability after the publisher has been configured.  I was wondering if there is any problems doing it the other way around so we don't have to change our existing mirroring configuration, we just add the publication and configure the replication options accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right in the link you cited.

> Configuring replication and database
>   mirroring involves five steps. Each
>   step is described in more detail in
>   the following section.
>
> 1. Configure the Publisher.
> 2. Configure database mirroring.
> 3. Configure the mirror to use the same
>      Distributor as the principal.
> 4. Configure replication agents for
>      failover.
> 5. Add the principal and mirror to
>      Replication Monitor.
>
> **Steps 1 and 2 can also be performed in
>   the opposite order.**[emphasis added]

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry to waste your time when the answer was in front of me.